# Why is a question "grayed out"?

Tags: support

This [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100135/monitoring-the-ph-level-while-neutralizing-a-base-with-acid) is grayed out in the list of questions.

Why?

There doesn't seem to be anything odd about the formatting.

Comment: Could you please check your "Ignored Tags"? Are you ignoring any of the tags of that question?

Comment: @Loong - Yes that was the problem. I finally figured out that you could hover over the tags in the list of questions to find out if one had been ignored. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Dah, just realized that there is a list named "Ignored Tags" in the right hand column of the view that shows the list of new questions.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you had ignored a certain set of tags, and that grayed question had one or more of those ignored tags.

Also see the relevant [Meta.SE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/256391).